# How do you put two divs next to each other so they fill up the available space

Tags: css, css-float

I have two divs, the right one is 80px wide the other should fill up the remaining space. So far I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #left {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 80px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #right {
            float: right;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
            width: 80px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the right box is always put below the left box and not right to it. I guess it is because of the margin. I also tried a margin-left: -80px on the right one but this doesnt seem to change anything. So how do I have to change the CSS so that the right div is in the same line as the left div?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have the right `div` before the left.

```
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d6xNS/2/)

Comment: This works, and seems to be the easiest of the suggested solutions. Thank you! What I don't get is, why this is working. Could you explain why?

Comment: Since elements are drawn in order, instead of moving down past the left element to draw the right, the right is drawn before and the left is drawn around the right element.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you're looking for the LEFT div to remain at a static width and the RIGHT div to expand and contract with the size of the page, you'd use the following code:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And the HTML would be...

```
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `div` is a block element, meaning it will always break the flow. What you can do is change both the div's `display` to `inline` and `float` to `left`.

Comment: using `display:inline` the content will define the width of the element, with result the `#left` element don't extent to the right side without use a `width`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `position:relative;` of `#right` to `position:absolute;top:0;right:0;`.
This will position the element in the right-top corner of its parent.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WaQGW/

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it can be done with `flex`.

Set container's (`body` in this case) `display` property to `flex`, then set width of left `div` to `100%`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

#left {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#right {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>
</body>
</html>
```